# Putting button (outside <form>) on the same line as input fields?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my html form:

```
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
    <label ng-hide="tab==1">Reviews Min: <input type="number" ng-init="revNum=30" class="form-control review-input" min="0" step="10" ng-model="filterValues.revNum" /></label>
    <label>Min Price &#163;: <input type="number" ng-init="filterValues.minNum=0" class="form-control price-input" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="filterValues.minNum" /></label>
    <label>Max Price &#163;: <input type="number" ng-init="filterValues.maxNum=0" class="form-control price-input" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="filterValues.maxNum" /></label>
    <label><select class="form-control" ng-model="filterValues.currentCarType"  style="display:block;" ng-options="key for key in carTypeObj">
        <option value="">Select Type</option>
    </select></label>
</form>
<label><button class="btn btn-primary " style="display:block;" ng-click="resetNumArray(); resetActiveRow(); resetType()">reset</button></label>
```

Here is my css:

```
.simple-form label{
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}

.simple-form button{
    background-color: #31708f;  
}

.price-input {
    width: 150px !important;
}
.review-input{
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

Here is an output in chrome:

[image]

Here is an output in firefox:

[image]

So my reset button is lower then my input fields and select, I need it to be on the same line. But if I move it inside `<form>`, when I write some value in my input field and press `Enter` my input field is resetting.
Also as you see, firefox is not displaying my `<select>` appropriately.

**How can I fix those problems?**

Here is an expected output in both browsers:

[image]

NOTE: I am using Bootstrap.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3Luab2p/1/)

Comment: jsfiddle don't have bootstap

Comment: You can add an external resource in Fiddle. And where is 'Min price' in Firefox?

Comment: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aqkgmah0/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v3Luab2p/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v3Luab2p/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And another working example at http://jsfiddle.net/dsqc10du/6/

Vertically aligning the select to the bottom of the form

```
.simple-form{
    display: inline-block;
}
.simple-form label{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

button{
   vertical-align: top !important;
   margin-top: 20px !important;
}
```